# passing a splited value from js to a Django view

Tags: javascript, django, model-view-controller

When I split some value with the JS code it sends splited data to the view with ',' delimiter
Can I change the delimiter ',' sent to the view ?
I know that the split functions accepts only two arguments .split(delimiter, limit)
Here's the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#searchSubmit').click(function() {
    q = $('#q').val().split('\n');
    t = $('#t').val();
    $('#results').html('&nbsp;').load('/?mdhash=' + q + '&type=' + t);
});
});
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
$('#spinner').show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
$('#spinner').hide();
});
```

And here's the part of the view:

```
def crackit(self, request):
    self.mdhash    = request.GET.get('mdhash', '').split(',')[:15]
    self.type      = request.GET.get('type', '')
    self.api       = request.GET.get('api', '')
    self.clear     = {}
    self.temp      = {}
    self.new       = {}
    self.encrypted = {}
    Remote_ip      = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR').split(':')[-1]
    current_path   = request.get_full_path()
```

Comment: q is a mdhash or ...? also please read http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS `split()` returns an array, and you're tring to put array into the string, it's bad. You cant be sure how exactly JS casts array to string. So [`join()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) array or take an element from it before concatenating it to url. You can also provide any separator to `join()`